# notations for implication vs. equivalence

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus

I would like to write the following as a way to make a statement that
the equivalence is the same as two implications
that work both ways:

$P \Leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow (P \Rightarrow Q \land Q \Rightarrow P)$

But this is circular. I suppose I could write instead:

$P \Leftrightarrow Q = (P \Rightarrow Q \land Q \Rightarrow P)$

But this begs the question:

If $P$ and $Q$ are propositions, what is
the difference between $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ and $P = Q$?

Also, what is the difference between:

- $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$
- $\Rightarrow$ and $\rightarrow$

I notice that the Wikipedia article on [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) is
using the $\leftrightarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ notations exclusively.

What is, then, the proper realm where the $\Leftrightarrow$ and
$\Rightarrow$ notations are meant to be used? I remember that we were
using $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ when solving equations, e.g.
writing things like:

$x^2 = y^2 \Leftrightarrow |x|=|y|$

… and:

$x = y \Rightarrow x^2 = y^2$ (since using $\Leftrightarrow$ here would be a mistake)

Comment: As a typesetting (not mathematical) comment, using `\iff` and `\implies` instead of `\Leftrightarrow` and `\Rightarrow` in $x^2=y^2 \iff |x|=|y|$ and $x=y \implies x^2 = y^2$ produces better spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ are used for *logical* implication and equivalence respectively, while $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are used for *material* implication.

The difference is that $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are logical operators, while $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ are *meta-logical* symbols used to express something *about* logic statements.

So, you can write $P \leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow (P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P)$ to express that the two logic statements $P \leftrightarrow Q$ and $(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P)$ are logically equivalent.

Unfortunately, not all texts follow this notation, and particularly confusing is the use of $\Rightarrow $ and $\Leftrightarrow $ for material implication.

Also, instead of $\Leftrightarrow$, many texts use $=$ when doing boolean algebra, but others will reserve $=$ to express that two statements are syntactically identical.